# AngularJS select check data and insert

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am angularjs newbie. I try to use ionic framework to do a practice, so that will use angularjs. And I got a little problem. I want to before insert data to check this data have exist, if not exist that will insert a new data.

On this method `getContent.then(function(res){})`, I will check this return `res.length`, if equal 0 I want insert this data. When I run, that will execute this console, and `obj` is have data. But at finally, I want get all data, but the data is empty.

But I found If I remove this insert method outside `getContent.then(function(res){})`, it's work. I have no idea how to fix this problem and cause this reason.

Thanks your help.

This is my Controller code

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['sqlite.services'])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http, Tests, SQLService) {
  SQLService.setup();
  var new_tests = new Array();

  $http.get('https://XXXXX').then(function(response){
    var datas = response.data;
    for (data_ in datas) {
      var obj = {
        id: datas[data_].content_id,
        title: datas[data_].title,
        url: datas[data_].url,
        content: datas[data_].content
      };

      var getContent = SQLService.get_one(obj.id);
      getContent.then(function(res) {
        console.log('res ' , res);
        console.log('res ' , res.length); // length get 0

        if(res.length == 0) {
          console.log('insert obj ' , obj);
          console.log('SQLService ' , SQLService);
          SQLService.insert(obj);
        }
        else if (res.length == 1) {
          console.log('edit obj ' , obj);
        }
      });

      // SQLService.insert(obj); // If I write insert code here is work for me

      new_tests.push(obj);
    }
  })
  .finally(function() {
    SQLService.all().then(function (results) {
      $scope.tests = results;
      console.log('results ' , results);
    });
  });
```

This is my sql_service.js

```
angular.module('sqlite.services', [])
.factory('SQLService', function($q) {
  var db;

  function createDB() {
    try {
      if (window.cordova) {
        $cordovaSQLite.deleteDB("my.db");
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: 'my.db'}); // device
      }
      else{
        db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
      }

      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pixnet (id integer not null primary key autoincrement, content_id text, title text, url, text, content text)", []);
      });
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log('Error processing SQL: ' + err);
    }

    console.log('database created');
  }

  function insertNewContent(newContent) {
    console.log('--insert--');
    return promisedQuery("INSERT INTO pixnet (content_id, title, url, content) VALUES ('" + newContent.id + "', '" + newContent.title + "', '" + newContent.url + "', '" + newContent.content + "')", defaultResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
  }

  function getContents() {
    return promisedQuery("SELECT * FROM pixnet", defaultResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
  }

  function updateContent(content){
    console.log('update content ' , content);
    return promisedQuery("UPDATE pixnet SET title='" + content.title + "', content='" + content.content + "' WHERE content_id = '" + content.id + "'", defaultResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
  }

  function getContent(content_id) {
    return promisedQuery("SELECT * FROM pixnet WHERE content_id = '" + content_id + "'", defaultResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
  }

  function defaultResultHandler(deferred) {
    return function(tx, results) {
    console.log('defaultResultHandler results ' , results);
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var output_results = [];

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
      var t = {
        'id': results.rows.item(i).id,
        'content_id': results.rows.item(i).content_id,
        'title': results.rows.item(i).title,
        'url': results.rows.item(i).url,
        'content': results.rows.item(i).content
      };
      output_results.push(t);
    }

    deferred.resolve(output_results);
    }
  }

  function defaultErrorHandler(deferred) {
    return function(tx, results) {
    var len = 0;
    var output_results = '';
    deferred.resolve(output_results);
    }
  }

  function promisedQuery(query, successCB, errorCB) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    db.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql(query, [], successCB(deferred), errorCB(deferred));
    }, errorCB);
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    setup: function() {
      return createDB();
    },
    insert: function(content) {
      return insertNewContent(content);
    },
    edit: function(content) {
      return updateContent(content);
    },
    get_one: function(content_id) {
      return getContent(content_id);
    },
    all: function() {
      return getContents();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what's happening is that the 'deferred' you create in promiseQuery is never resolved:

```
 function promisedQuery(query, successCB, errorCB) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql(query, [], successCB(deferred), errorCB(deferred));
     }, errorCB);
     return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Since you are using cordova sqlite plugin, looking at the source code we see the third argument of the 'transaction' function is the success callback.

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin/blob/master/www/SQLitePlugin.js#L74

So this means you want to resolve your promise in either of those callbacks. Try the following:

```
 function promisedQuery(query, successCB, errorCB) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql(query, [], successCB(deferred), errorCB(deferred));
     }, errorCB, deferred.resolve);
     return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Passing the deferred.resolve function into the success callback (the last argument of transaction) will get it called when the transaction finishes.

Comment: Thanks your help, I have write deferred on this two method `defaultResultHandler`, `defaultErrorHandler`. I have edit my code.

Comment: i just edited my question. your additional code doesn't help though. I need to see the 'transaction' function

Comment: Very very thanks your help again. I have edit my question again, and post all my sql_service.js code.

Comment: Thanks you. I change my code, and it work. And I think this problem is like you say, it is defer's problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    angular.module('starter.controllers', ['sqlite.services'])
      .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http, Tests, SQLService) {
          SQLService.setup();
          var new_tests = new Array();

          var call_async_in_loop = function(obj) {
            var getContent = SQLService.get_one(obj.id);
            getContent.then(function(res) {
              console.log('res ', res);
              console.log('res ', res.length); // length get 0

              if (res.length == 0) {
                console.log('insert obj ', obj);
                console.log('SQLService ', SQLService);
                SQLService.insert(obj);
              } else if (res.length == 1) {
                console.log('edit obj ', obj);
              }
            });

          }

          $http.get('https://XXXXX').then(function(response) {
              var datas = response.data;
              for (data_ in datas) {
                var obj = {
                  id: datas[data_].content_id,
                  title: datas[data_].title,
                  url: datas[data_].url,
                  content: datas[data_].content
                };

                call_async_in_loop(obj)
                new_tests.push(obj);
              }
            })
            .finally(function() {
              SQLService.all().then(function(results) {
                $scope.tests = results;
                console.log('results ', results);
              });
            });
```

You loosing the reference to obj because of the async call SQLService.get_one(obj.id). When the promise is resolved the for loop is already finished. So u have to create a closure to keep reference to obj.

Comment: I think the problem is not `obj`. Cause I have `console.log` the obj  on the insert method. That data is not empty.

Comment: you tried it? because it sounds like this if it works outside of then but not inside.

Comment: I'm have try it, but i have no idea how can I create callback on the controller. Can you give me a example? Thanks.

Comment: I try it, but I get this error message `TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at call_async_in_loop (controllers.js:35)`